# Using 'lftp' as a FTPS (not SFTP) client on SuSE Linux ES 11

Tags: vsftpd, lftp

I have to configure `lftp` as a FTPS client to be used on a system with SuSe Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP1 installed on it. For that, I have downloaded `lftp-4.6.1` and executed following command in order to install it:

`./configure --with-openssl --without-gnutls --with-debug`

The installation process exits with the following error:

`configure: error: openssl development library not found for MD5`

I am not able to figure out what package is to be installed so as to remove the error and complete the installation process.

Note: FTPS server is setup using `vsftpd`.

Comment: [`libopenssl-devel` probably](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?q=opensuse+openssl-devel). (I don't know for sure, though.)

Comment: Can we use OpenSuse packages in SLES?

Comment: I have no experience with either, but I think they have a reverse of the CentOS/RHEL relationship, so I'd say yes. In either case, see if you can use your usual package manager to instal it. The package name should remain the same.

Comment: I faced similar kind of error while installing lftp on RHEL and the package needed was `readline-devel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the list of packages needed to be installed:

`libopenssl-devel-0.9.8h-30.27.11.x86_64.rpm
zlib-devel-1.2.3-106.34.x86_64.rpm
readline-devel-5.2-147.9.13.x86_64.rpm
ncurses-devel-5.6-90.55.x86_64.rpm
tack-5.6-90.55.x86_64.rpm
libncurses6-5.6-90.55.x86_64.rpm`